# For a given function $f$ and $\varepsilon = 1$, find $\delta$ such that $0<|x-3|<\delta$ implies $|f(x) - 4| < \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

I'm currently learning the precise/formal/$\varepsilon-δ$ definition of a limit.

Let  $f(x) = x^3 -9x^2 + 27x -23$

We know: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 3} f(x)=4$

For each given value of $\varepsilon > 0$, I'd like to find a corresponding value $δ > 0$ such that:

$$0 < |x-3| < δ \implies |f(x)-4| < \varepsilon$$

Here's my professor's steps for when $\varepsilon = 1:$

1. $|f(x)-4|<1$
2. $-1 < f(x)-4 < 1$
3. $3 < f(x) < 5$
4. $2 < x < 4$
5. $-1 < x-3 < 1$

How did he get to step $4$ and $5$? Is it complete at step $5$ and does $δ = 1$?

I'm very confused, I've been doing research on finding $δ$ when $\varepsilon$ is given. I've found very few examples on this topic, and nothing with $f(x)$ when being compared to as less than $\varepsilon$.

I know how to do proofs but I just can't understand this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Who is the $f$?

Comment: f(x)? I'm sorry I forgot to include

f(x) = x^3 -9x^2+27x-23
lim f(x) = 4 as x->3

Comment: In the future, OP, [please make use of LaTeX/MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/597568). Posts not using them can be nigh-unreadable at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple enough. On the small interval we're concerned about, where $3 < f(x) < 5$, $f$ is invertible and monotone-increasing. You can see this from the graph:

[image]

Therefore, we apply the inverse function and preserve the inequality:

$$f^{-1}(3) < f^{-1}(f(x)) < f^{-1}(5)$$

Of course, $f^{-1}(y)$ is just asking "what $x$ ensures that $f(x) = y$?" You can solve this algebraically or by any other method of your preference, but the graph clearly suggests that

$$f^{-1}(3) = 2 \qquad f^{-1}(5) = 4$$

Definitionally, $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$, so we now have

$$2 < x < 4$$

The subsequent step is just subtracting $3$. This is because we want $x-3$ to pop up, to match our $\delta$ inequality, and because we get

$$-1 < x-3 < 1 \iff |x-3| < 1$$

i.e. because it's nice enough that we get $\pm 1$ on each side of the inequality, very conducive to the use of the absolute value.

It is from this, then, that we are suggested that $\delta = 1$ works.

Comment: I'm curious as to what at a precalc level justifies knowing its monotonic there (As you wouldn't just be able to graph it with that).   Maybe # of 0 theorems and turning points....

Comment: Well, luckily, it looks like this function takes the form $(x-3)^3 + 4$, so that'd make it a lot easier. Without being able to somehow ascertain that, I'd just have to make an argument that asserts it's invertible, e.g. it is strictly increasing on the values we care about and this-and-that are the inputs generating the endpoints.

Comment: I am so sorry, I deleted my comment because I found an answer, thank you for your reply!